# How do I add a download file to 'my downloadable product' sections of each customer on Magento?

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.6.1.0. How do I add a download file to 'my downloadable product' sections of each customer on Magento? Every existing and new customers should see this file when he accesses his/Her account.

Comment: can you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: I am the beginning and have no code at the moment.

Comment: ok, so what is your thinking? can you describe what thought you've put into it? StackOverflow encourages users to attempt to solve it yourself and then have the community help rather than provide whole solutions...

Answer (score 1):

This aspect, just put downloadable contents into whole registered customers dashboard section. Customers should login then see the content. But, as you might guest, it's not protected content, everybody can download if they know the links!

Open **dashboard.phtml**

```
# file : dashboard.phtml  
# path : app/design/frontend/[your_namespace]/[your_theme]/template/customer/account  
// put the following line after 'address' section  
<div class="download-links">  
   <h4><?php echo $this->__('Download Manuals') ?></h4>  
</div>  
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('downloadlinks') ?>
```

Open **customer.xml**

```
# file : customer.xml  
# path : app/design/frontend/[your_namespace]/[your_theme]/layout/customer.xml  
// add the following line  
<block type="core/template" name="customer_manual_links" as ="downloadlinks” template="downloadlinks/downloads.phtml"/>
```

Create folder **downloadlinks** and put the `downloads.phtml`

```
# file : downloads.phtml
# path : app/design/frontend/[your_namespace]/[your_theme]/template/downloadlinks/
<span>Your downloadable manuals</span>
<a href="">Product Catalog PDF</a><br/>
<a href="">Product Manual PDF</a><br/>
```

Comment: Oğuz thank you very much for this valuable code. Is there a way to implement this to the existing My Downloadable Products section of the customer account page?

Comment: @user1008832 check `downloadable.xml` in `app/design/frontend/[namespace]/[theme]/layout/` you will see a section which is define "My Downloadable Products" area. The file responsible of the "My Downloadable Products" area is `list.phtml`

Comment: you should put `customer.xml` content in `downloadable.xml` file then modify the `list.phtml`.